# How to show records vertically one by one

Tags: rdlc

I am using RDLC in asp.net. I want to show the record in this way:

Trace ID: 12345 
Address:  flat 123, Big Mansion 
Street: street 123

Trace ID: 56789 
Address:  flat 567, Big Mansion 
Street: street 567

How can I do that? As I do not know the keyword to search in web. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: I mean can I show the record one by one vertically. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a `List`, the data source of which contains all the records. In the final report, the `List` will be replicated for each record in the data set.

Within the `List` you can place other controls as you whish and attach them to fields within the data set.

Comment: Thanks Dittmar. So if I search the internet. What keyword should I use? Thanks